# ¿Cómo funciona la firma criptográfica al pie de página de un PDF?

Tags: pdf, seguridad, firma-digital, criptografía

He estado queriendo entender cómo funcionan las firmas digitales en los PDFs, o en general en los archivos.

Entiendo cómo es que se genera una firma digital a partir de una llave privada y un conjunto de bits, pero todavía no logro entender cómo se hace con los PDFs para agregarle como pie de página la firma del propio PDF, mi lógica es la siguiente.

1. Digamos que tienes un conjunto de bits `xyz` (el PDF) y tu llave privada, y quieres:

   - Generar la firma del PDF con esa llave
   - Añadir la firma al PDF
2. Entonces, digamos que la firma digital generada es `abc` y se la añadimos al los bits `xyz` (por ejemplo, al agregar la firma digital al pie de página), resultando en que el PDF ya no contiene los bits `xyz` originales, sino ahora contiene `xyzabc` (los originales más los añadidos de la firma digital)
3. Luego entonces, la firma agregada al pdf no es válida para el propio pdf, pues este está compuesto de los bits `xyzabc`, mientras que la firma fue utilizada para firmar el PDF original que contenía los bits `xyz`

Entonces,

¿Cómo se haría en ese caso la verificación de la firma?

¿Habría que remover por completo los bits que componen a la firma para quedarnos sólo con el documento original (los bits `xyz`)?

¿En otras palabras a los bits `xyzabc` quitarles los bits de la firma `abc` y verificar que esa firma corresponde a los bits `xyz` y a la llave pública?

Comment: Hay una explicación muy básica en la [documentación](https://acrobat.adobe.com/es/es/sign/digital-signatures.html) de Adobe. Tal vez, aunque explican el proceso muy someramente es bastante parecido a lo que planteas en tu pregunta. Saludos

Comment: Muchas gracias @MauricioContreras, ya revisé la documentación que compartiste, sin embargo no me resolvió la duda que tengo. Quisiera conocer cómo se hace "manualmente" o cuál es la lógica que por ejemplo, Adobe Sign o cualquier otro programa sigue para verficar una firma digital

Comment: No se como funciona en PDF, lo he hecho con XML: primero generas el XML, luego calculas la firma usando tu clave privada e insertas un elemento nuevo en el XML con la firma. Para validar el documento _primero se remueve la firma_ y se verifica que ésta sea válida (en mi caso con certificados de seguridad). Luego, se compara el XML con lo indicado en la firma, y si el documento no fue modificado entonces la firma será coherente con el XML.

Comment: Algunas bibliotecas traen métodos que tienen este propósito, por ejemplo, PDFBox tiene el método [CreateVisibleSignature2](https://pdfbox.apache.org/docs/2.0.11/javadocs/org/apache/pdfbox/examples/signature/CreateVisibleSignature2.html). Puedes revisar [esta respuesta de SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44311502/in-java-using-pdfbox-how-to-create-visible-digital-signature-with-text/48232829#48232829)